# All installed OSes freeze on boot up (archlinux + windows)

Tags: linux, windows, boot, freeze, hardware-failure

Over the last weekend, my system has developed an aversion to booting into any OS.

I have 3 SSDs with OS installed on them:

- Sabrent nvme: Windows 10 (2004)
- Samsung 860: Windows 10 (1909)
- Samsung 840: Archlinux (kernel 5.7.x, updated on 12th or 13th May)

The nvme was purchased recently, and to install windows on it I had to disconnect all other connected drives. Installation went smoothly. I had also replugged other drives. The system worked fine for 3-4 days (10th to 14th).

From this week's Monday whenever I try to boot, it leads to the bootloader screen, I select one of the 3 options.

The kernel/os boots up and takes me to login screen (windows) or the xdm (arch). I input password and within 10-15 seconds of me inputting the password; the whole system freezes.

This is happening consistently for each and every boot I try; each and every OS I have installed and with the exception that for linux, sometimes it doesn't even get to the xdm login screen.

I read that the issue might be memory(?), created a memtest boot drive and ran the tests. After around 12 hours of tests, memtest reported 0 errors for the 48 tests it ran.

I am at my wit's end now on how to debug the root cause for the same. Because of the lockdown around my area, the service centers are also not accepting any submissions for testing.

#### memtest results

[image: memtest results]

[image: memtest]

Any pointers would be really helpful.

### EDIT/UPDATE

After following the suggestion [from comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1561960/all-installed-oses-freeze-on-boot-up-archlinux-windows?noredirect=1#comment2378150_1561960), I removed the hardwares except kb/m (webcam and steam controller usb device); switched off the GPU (disconnected power, didn't detach from mobo). I didn't remove any of the drives or any of the ram sticks.

Tried booting the windows from sabrent nvme with the onboard GPU, and the system froze again. This made me confirm that the issue is not with graphics card.

Switched my gpu back on, and on booting the system again; this time it didn't freeze. I am currently logged in for about 2 hours. Have launched some games in parallel (to stress ram+cpu+drives). No issues faced so far. Will try to reboot after taking few backups in case I might need to format any of the drives soon.

Comment: Try ruling out some hardware issues. Leave only once disk connected, remove all unnecessary hardware including graphics card, use the onboard one. Disconnect all USB devices except for keyboard. If the issue persist, reset CMOS and try again. If it doesn't, start adding removed hardware one by one. Try to update BIOS if it's not the latest.

Comment: @gronostaj check the edit/update section